# Conditional Poisson Process events arriving into two categories with probability $\frac{1}{3}$ and $\frac{2}{3}$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, poisson-process

Suppose that people come in according to a Poisson process of rate $\lambda = 20$ per hour. Suppose further that each person that arrives goes into house $A$ with probability $\frac{1}{3}$ and into house $B$ with probability $\frac{2}{3}$. Assume that a total of $100$ people arrived in the first $10$ hours. Conditional on this, I would like to find the probability that $n(n ≤ 100)$ people arrived into **house A** in  the first $4$ hours.

Generally, I know that without the houses:

\begin{align}
P(X(4)=N|X(10) = 100) &= \frac{P(X(4)=N,X(10) = 100)}{P(X(10) = 100)} \\
&= \frac{P(X(4)=N,X(10)-X(4) = 100-N)}{P(X(10) = 100)} \\
&= \frac{P(X(4)=N)\cdot P(X(10)-X(4) = 100-N)}{P(X(10) = 100)} \\
&= {100\choose N}\left(\frac{4}{6}\right)^N\left(\frac{6}{10}\right)^{100}
\end{align}

To find the probability of $n$ people arriving into house $A$, I define that $N=N_1+N_2$, where $N$ is total people, $N_1$ people in house $A$, $N_2$ people in house $B$ and I have that:

\begin{align}
P(X(4) = N, N_1=n|X(10)=100)&=  \sum_{i=0}^{100-n}P(X(4) = N_1+N_2, N_1=n, N_2 = i|X(10)=100)\\
&= \sum_{i=0}^{100-n}P(X(4) = n+i, N_1=n, N_2 = i|X(10)=100)\\
\end{align}

At this point, I am not sure how to factor out the joint distribution of the last line. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Simply concatenate results you already know... Conditionally on N people arriving in H hours, the number of people arriving in h hours from these H hours is binomial (N,h/H). Conditionally on n people arriving in h hours, the number of people arriving in house A in these h hours is binomial (n,p) where p=1/3 is the probability to choose house A. Thus, conditionally on N people arriving in H hours, the number of people arriving in house A in h hours from these H hours is binomial (n,ph/H). Note that the Poisson process part is simply irrelevant.

Comment: @Did How would the conditional argument formally look for the second part you wrote in terms of variables? I am having trouble explicitly writing down $n$ and relating it to $N_A$ and $N_B$ for the number that go to house $A$ versus house $B$.  Would it look like $P(N_A(h) = n_A|X(h) = n) \sim Bin(n,p)$? Or would it look like $P(N_A(h) = n_A|X(h) = n, N_A(h)+N_B(h) = n) \sim Bin(n,p)$?

Comment: @Did Shouldn't your last line be binomial(N, ph/H) instead of binomial(n,ph/H)?

Comment: It should, good catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The arrivals in house $A$ follow a Poisson process with parameter $λ_A=\frac1320$ per hour. Hence, you can ignore arrivals to house $B$ and only adapt your first part and your are done.

---

Note, that the last line of your first calculation in the first part seems to have two mistakes. It should be $$\dbinom{100}{N}\left(\frac4{10}\right)^N\left(\frac6{10}\right)^{100-N}$$

Comment: Formally, what property here makes it so that the parameter for $A$ is $\frac{1}{3}20$?

Comment: @user321627 It is called the decomposition property of Poisson process. But, if you have not done it, then perhaps you cannot use and you need to prove it. I mean, that the proof (which is not super difficult) may be part of the exercise.

Comment: I see, that definitely makes things more straight forward. Do you know if I would be able to calculate out my result from my last line above?

Comment: @user321627 Your last line does not seem correct. $n+i>n$, hence how is it possible that there arrived $n+i$ in $4$ hours if in ten hours, there arrived $N_1=n<n+i$ people. But you can prove that the arrivals in House A indeed follow Poisson with $λ=\frac1320$ (just search for decomposition property proof) and then use your part 1. Your second part seems unnecessarily complicated to me. (someone else may have another insight).

Comment: I am not saying that there are $N_1 = n$ people in 10 hours but rather I am trying to sum through all possible combinations in the conditions to retrieve that probability